# The changes that I put onto the GoDaddy server with Dreamweaver CC will not show up right away

Tags: browser, server

Recently I have been uploading changes to the GoDaddy hosting server for our website using Dreamweaver CC.  Sometimes the changes show up right away and sometimes the changes don't show up for hours or even a day.  I have tried clearing the browsing data on multiple browsers to no avail.  I have tried disabling the cache in the developer tool panel.  I have even tried inserting the following code that I found on StackOverflow:

```
> <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store,
> must-revalidate">
>     <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
>     <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
```

All of this has not worked.  I have conducted an experiment with another hosting server, "JustHost" and whatever I upload to that server always shows up right away.
GoDaddy told me that the internet sometimes doesn't "assimilate" information right away sometimes and that is why there is a delay.  This seems strange to me, since I have never, ever had this issue in past years.  So, how do I force the changes to show up on the internet that I've uploaded to the server???  There must be a way to strong arm the internet into complying.
Thanks in advance,
Dale

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a cache issue, just need to find which cache is at fault.

**Try loading the site on an online proxy** like http://anonymouse.org/ Any other ONLINE proxy will do the job, but I use this one.

If the site shows the latest changes you made it means GoDaddy is working fine and that this is a cache issue on your side. It can be your ISP doing some caching for you (usually on cheap contracts to save bandwidth, but unlikely) but sometimes your computer also will store cache in deeper places than your browser. Usually my cache troubleshooting goes like this:

1. Try **refreshing the page** a couple of times.
2. Try **CTRL+F5**.
3. Try **loading the page on another browser** (if this fails, means your ISP is caching the pages for you. Unfortunately you will have to wait or you can use CloudflareWARP.
4. Try adding a random number to your URL parameters, this forced to ignore the cache. For example http://example.com/index.html?24601.
5. Open **cmd.exe** and type `ipconfig /flushdns` (particularly when I it's a new website or have change server setting).
6. **Delete all cache and cookies** (I hate doing this because you loose everything, that's why for me is the last resource).

Usually by this stage it works or you have established where's the issue.